# Javascript Regex to pull id from string works for 3/5 cases

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex to pull an id from a facebook url. The url can be in any form of the following. I have also listed the result of the regex.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/1234567890 >>> 1234567890
https://graph.facebook.com/1234567890:0 >>> 1234567890:0
https://graph.facebook.com/&id=1234567890 >>> 1234567890
```

These are all fine, and what I want. Here are the 2 that are NOT what I want:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/1234567890/picture >>> picture
https://graph.facebook.com/1234567890/ >>> 1234567890/
```

Here is my regex:
`([^\/|=]*?)(?:\/|:[0-9])?$`

From the last 2, what I want is 1234567890. No trailing slash, and no non-digit characters.

1. I know my regex is continuing to the end of the string, hence pulling in the match between starting slash and end of string being 'picture', but I have tried to resolve this to no avail.
2. The trailing slash seems related to this also, but again, I cannot resolve these 2 issues without breaking the original working 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a simple regex to match *any numbers in the URL* which may include a `:`. The assumption for this to work is that the URL will not contain any other ID's other than the one which has to be extracted

```
\d+(?::\d+)?
```

- `\d+` allows one or more numbers
- `:\d+` indicates a `:` followed by one or more numbers
- `(?::\d+)?` indicates that this non-capturing group may or may not be present

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Oa9c2A/2/)

Comment: This is a fantastic answer. First because it is so much cleaner and simple than mine, and second, because you have explained what is going on to newbie regex people like me. This greatly reduces the need to post further similar questions and aids in further understanding of regex. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you! Glad I could help. I'd recommend starting off [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info) and also making use of [regex101](https://regex101.com) to play around and learn regex. It easily offers one of the best step-by-step explanations and test area, plus support for various engines too!